# MariaDB czech characters

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table in MariaDB called table1 with utf8 character set

There are following records

```
field1
Jiri Cerveny
Jiří Červený
Jiri Červeny
Jiři Červený
```

The following statement "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='Jiri Cerveny';"

I would expect, it will respond with 1 record only, but I am receiving all 4 records.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks
Jiri

Comment: Most likely you will need to change the character set of your table to something which supports accented characters.  And existing data might not be migrated.

Comment: Also, which operating system?

Comment: It is serviced by Linux CentOS. According to the table, SQLFIDDLE is following http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3da7f/1

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper [collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html) in your search.

Assuming *utf8_czech_ci*, you should do :

```
SELECT field1  
FROM table1 
WHERE field1='Jiri Cerveny' collate utf8_czech_ci;
```

Test :

```
create table table1 (field1 VARCHAR(50)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('Jiri Cerveny');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('Jiří Červený');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('Jiri Červeny');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('Jiři Červený');
```

With normal query

```
SELECT field1  FROM table1  WHERE field1='Jiri Cerveny'

|       field1 |
|--------------|
| Jiri Cerveny |
| Jiří Červený |
| Jiri Červeny |
| Jiři Červený |
```

With collation :

```
SELECT field1  FROM table1 WHERE field1='Jiri Cerveny' collate utf8_czech_ci;

|       field1 |
|--------------|
| Jiri Cerveny |
```

or

```
SELECT field1  FROM table1 WHERE field1='Jiri Červeny' collate utf8_czech_ci;

|       field1 |
|--------------|
| Jiri Červeny |
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/689814/1)

Comment: It seems, there is a problem with my original table. SQLFIDDLE is included > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3da7f/1

Comment: The `ř` and the `Č` do what you want with utf8_czech_ci.  But 'ý' = 'y'.  I think the same happens with MySQL 8.0 and its utf8mb4_czech_ci.  [_Here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) is a rundown of the collations.